# Unable to get Hadoop job information through java client

Tags: java, hadoop

Am using Hadoop 1.2.1 and trying to print Job details through java client but it is not printing anything, here is my java code

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    configuration.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
    configuration.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml")); 
    InetSocketAddress jobtracker = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 54311);
    JobClient jobClient;
    jobClient = new JobClient(jobtracker, configuration);
    jobClient.setConf(configuration);
    JobStatus[] jobs = jobClient.getAllJobs();
    System.out.println(jobs.length);//it is printing 0.
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        JobStatus js = jobs[i];
        JobID jobId = js.getJobID();
        System.out.println(jobId);
    }
```

But from job tracker history i can see three jobs. Here is the screen shot
[image]
Can any body tell me where am going wrong. I just want to print all the job details.

And here is my configuration files :

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name
<value>/data/tmp</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose</description>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
<description>Default block replication.  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:54311</value>
<description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs at. If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map and reduce task.
</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `jobClient.getAllJobs()` accesses jobs that are already completed.

Comment: Thanks @Chaos, then how can i get completed jobs information.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
jobClient.displayTasks(jobID, "map", "completed");
```

where job ID is

```
JobID jobID = new JobID(jobIdentifier, jobNumber);
```

or

```
TaskReport[] taskReportList =   jobClient.getMapTaskReports(jobID);
```