# Hadoop: Job shows up in the job browser but unable to access the JobStatus via api

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, mapreduce

I have run an example hadoop job, and when I look at the Jobs area of the Hue web app I can see the details for my job. I would like to access this info programmatically... I wrote the following code as a test:

```
JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(new Configuration());
JobStatus[] jobStatuses = jobClient.getAllJobs();
System.out.println("Found " + jobStatuses.length + " job statuses.");
for(JobStatus jobStatus : jobStatuses) {
    System.out.println(jobStatus.getJobID());
}
jobClient.close();
```

Output is: "Found 0 job statuses."

Other details - I testing this using the CDH4 standalone VM. I am using the conf files from /etc/hadoop/conf/conf.cloudera.yarn1 (using the /etc/hadoop/conf ones did not work).

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412423/unable-to-get-hadoop-job-information-through-java-client) seems related but is unanswered as well...

What are some areas that I could investigate to sort this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research I determined that I was using the mr2 (yarn) compatible jars instead of the mr1 compatible jars. I changed my pom.xml appropriately and the problems magically went away.